# Callback ignored issue in node.js running on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, callback, aws-lambda

I have this code in node.js (nodejs10.x) running in AWS Lambda.

```
module.exports.register = (event, context, callback) => {

  // Body es un json por lo que hay que deserializarlo
  let body = JSON.parse(event.body);

  let rules = {
    'name': 'required|min:3',
    'family_name': 'required|min:3',
    'email': 'required|email',
    'curp': 'required|size:18',
    'modules': 'required',
    'password': 'required'
  };

  let validation = new validator(body, rules);

  // If errors this validation exits using the callback
  if(validation.fails()){
    console.log(validation.errors.all())
    const response = {
      statusCode: 422,
      body: JSON.stringify(validation.errors.all())
    };
    callback(null, response);
  }

  // just for testing
  const isModulesValid = false;


  if(!isModulesValid){
    console.log('Modules validation failed. ')
    const response = {
      statusCode: 422,
      body: JSON.stringify({'modules': 'Invalid modules string. '})
    };
    callback(null, response);
    // However this is not working
  }

  // and even if there is an error this code is executed
  console.log('XXXX');
```

I am testing it locally with a code like this.

```
// Callback
let callback = function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  if (result)
    console.log(result);
  // Terminate execution once done
  process.exit(0);
}

// lambda.generateToken(event, context, callback);
lambda.register(event, context, callback);
```

Locally if isModulesValid = false the code exits and the console.log('XXXX') is not executed. However when running it in AWS Lambda, even if the validation fails the code continues to run and the console.log() is executed.

I cannot figure out whats going on. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Locally you are using the callback which has `process.exit(0);` which is making the process finish and hence the next line is not executing. Callback doesn't mean that the code afterwards wouldn't be executed. the code flow continues after that as well. It all depends on what you have in your callback.

Comment: I was suspicious about that. However the callback is given by the AWS Lambda runtime. Do you know what happens in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code solved the problem:

```
if(!isModulesValid){
    console.log('Modules validation failed. ')
    const response = {
      statusCode: 422,
      body: JSON.stringify({'modules': 'Invalid modules string. '})
    };
    // Return callback explcitly
    return callback(null, response);
  }
```

Apparently it has to do with how AWS Lambda handles the task queue. I found a good explanation here: https://blog.danillouz.dev/aws-lambda-and-the-nodejs-event-loop/